# Mostrar imagem enviada Phonegap + PHP

Tags: php, apache-cordova

Olá, eu estou utilizando o seguinte código para fazer upload da imagem de um app phonegap para um servidor :

```
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
    // Do cool things here...
    }

    function getImage() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
        alert('get picture failed');
    },{
        quality: 100, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,allowEdit: true,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    }
        );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";


        options.params = {
        email : localStorage.getItem('email')
        }
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://localhost/app/photo.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win() {

        location.href="settings.html";
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("Erro ao enviar foto!");
    }

    </script>
```

Aparentemente funciona sem problemas. Porém, eu estou usando o código php abaixo para verificar se o arquivo existe ou não, assim, se existir ele vai colocar a foto caso contrario ele coloca uma imagem padrão:

```
  $setphoto =     "http://localhost/app/_profile_photo/$userid.jpg";
  $photodefault = "http://localhost/app/_profile_photo/default-image.png";



if (file_exists($setphoto)){

   echo "<img src=\"$setphoto\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\">";

}

else{

    echo "<img src=\"$photodefault\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\">";
}
```

O problema é que a função file_exists() não está reconhecendo o arquivo enviado e sempre pega a foto padrão.

O que eu já testei:

1- Verifiquei se o $userid esta correto no caminho da foto. 
2- Usei a funcão como !file_exists() e ele passa a mostrar a imagem certo.
3- Colocar direto no html a imagem src="http://localhost/app/_profile_photo/aquiOIdDoUsuario.jpg"> - Mostra a imagem.

Eu preciso saber como fazer para a função file_exists() verificar que o arquivo está la.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo assim:

```
$filename= 'http://localhost/app/_profile_photo/$userid.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($filename);

if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
      echo "O file $filename não existe";
} else if ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found' && $file_headers[7] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
      echo "O file $filename não existe, e redirecionou para uma custom 404 page..";
} else {
      echo "The file $filename exists";
}
```

Retirado daqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444059/file-exists-returns-false-even-if-file-exist-remote-url

Comment: Olá Lucas, fiz as alterações conforme o código passado e neste caso ele aparece que o arquivo existe. Porém, eu deletei o arquivo e mesmo assim ele diz que existe.

Comment: Trocando o 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' por 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' funciona. Alguém saberia dizer porque e se é confiável no sentido de funcionar?